# How to add NOLOCK for Auto generated SQL queries in Loopback 3

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback3

I'm using Loopback 3 and SQL. We've 20 million rows in SQL tables and when we query data using Loopback it's taking a lot of time and further observation we found queries are blocking in SQL. Noticed that the Loopback auto generated queries doesn't have any `WITH (NOLOCK)`. How to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` for every `SELECT` query?

Comment: Which connector would you be using?

Comment: @KetanPatil loopback-connector-mssql

Answer (score 1):

Using `Transaction.READ_UNCOMMITTED` would produce `WITH (NOLOCK)`.

For example:

```js
YourModel.beginTransaction({isolationLevel: YourModel.Transaction.READ_UNCOMMITTED}, (err, tx) => {
  // Now we have a transaction (tx)
  // Write the queries here
  // Then run commit the transaction:
  tx.commit(err => {});
});
```

See [the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-database-transactions.html#start-transaction) for more details.

Comment: @KetanPatil Does it add NOLOCK ? I tried above one  already.. I'm not seeing nolock like SELECT  name FROM Employee WITH (NOLOCK)   in SQL Trace profiler.  I don't have inline quires to execute inside txns. I'm calling directly Model/Table

Comment: As per the documentation, it should `NOLOCK`

Comment: It should produce a transaction with READ UNCOMMITTED, which achieves the same result. Just that one applies to an entire transaction while the other only applies to that statement.

Comment: @KetanPatil 

Error: 1. YourModel.beginTransaction is not a function
          2. YourModel.Transaction.READ_UNCOMMITTED  / /YourModel.Transaction is undefined